# How to do data driven testing using jMeter if the values are present in the body not in parameters

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I know using of data driven in jMeter by passing the values in parameters, but my concern is how to the data driven testing when the values are sending in request of a **body**. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSV Data Set Config, **Add > Config Element > CSV Data Set Config**
In the CSV file you can set the value for the parameters.

**example csv file**
[image: Create a csv file in this format with header as the parameter name.]

**Provide csv file path in CSV Data Set Config**
[image: CSV Data Set Config]

Imported CSV file will be the data to perform data driven testing for login page, where first row of the csv file is variable name and rest is test data.
Set the **number of thread user**  under **Thread Group** same as number of rows present in the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screenshot]

Have you tried fill body like this?
MyVariable is user defined variable